# How can I paginate text of variable length?

Tags: javascript, pagination

is it possible to break a formatted text into multiple boxes, without preparing the text by someone? I have found several jQuery plugins which paginate such a text:

```
<div>
  <p>page 1</p>
  <p>page 2</p>
</div>
$("div").paginate();
```

but I want to paginate the text based on page height and width:

```
<p>page 1<br/>page 2</p>
$("p").paginate({ width: 20, height: 20 });
```

this way the pagination is flexible and no one needs to know where to set `<p></p>`.

More specific: I want to split a html-formatted text into multiple pages of a fixed size (e.g. 100x200px). The problem is that I don't know the real height of the output text (the parsed html text), and therefore I cannot split the text every x chars (also because that could destroy the html markup)

example text (tinymce output):

```
<div id="toPaginate">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h2>
<p>consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam&nbsp;nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
<ul>
<li>erat,</li>
<li>sed</li>
<li>diam</li>
<li>voluptua.</li>
</ul>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea <strong>rebum</strong>. <em>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est</em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h1>
<p>consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if im understanding what youre trying to do here. but if you want to split a article or like at certen hight/text length, you might wanner try inserting X chars of the text in to a p tag and then check the innerHeight of it.

Comment: the problem is not splitting the text into a fixed amount of chars. The problem is to find the amount of chars needed to fill a whole page. `<p>hello</p>` has a different size than `<p>hello<br/>you</p>`.

Comment: if you insert lets say 50 chars then check the hight then insert 50 chars more you can stop at the wanted height

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need can be written in one line, assuming the full text is initially contained in one `<p>`, give that paragraph an id and start your `.ready` callback with this:

```
$('#toPaginate').replaceWith('<p>'+$('#toPaginate').html().match(/(.{0,200})\b/g).join('</p><p>')+'</p>');
```

Where `toPaginate` is the id of the paragraph containing the text. In case of multiple paragraphs, just use a class:

```
$('.toPaginate').each(function()
{
    $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+$(this).html().match(/(.{0,200})\b/g).join('</p><p>')+'</p>');
});
```

Oh, this code will break your text up into chunks of 200 chars max. Just change the max in the regex (`/(.{0,200})\b/`) from 200 to whatever length you need.
I've set up [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDyZy/4) with some comments and an example using an IIFE, too.

To make the size of the *"pages"* depend on width and height, you can always use `em` measurements. `1em` === size of 1 char. In other words:

```
function paginate(width, height)
{
    var maxChars = width*height;
    maxChars = new RegExp('(.{0,'+maxChars+'})\\b','g');
    $('#toPaginate').replaceWith('<p>'+$('#toPaginate').html().match(maxChars).join('</p><p>')+'</p>');
}
```

With a class selector, replace `$('toPaginate')` by `this`, and use `paginate` as the `.each` callback function and that's it, obviously, `width` and `height` aren't going to be passed, but by using a closure you could set them correctly:

```
$('.toPaginate').each((function(width,height)
{
    var maxChars = new RegExp('(.{0,'+(width*height)+'})\\b','g');
    return function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+$(this).html().match(maxChars).join('</p><p>')+'</p>');
    };
}(50, 20)));//pass dimensions here
```

Check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDyZy/5/) to see it in action, this time I have taken the precaution of checking it first :s...

Comment: this will destroy any formatting in the text right? I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You mean `<br/>` tags and the like... I sort of assumed flat text, because when you add html to the mix, it takes some extra work: parse the html, get all the inner text etc... it can be done, but it'll take more than a simple regex. The above approach doesn't break the words as such, so you could set it to split on spaces _only_, too. I don't know what kind of markup you're dealing with either. Perhaps you could setup a fiddle? BTW: parsed html in jQuery has the `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` methods, so you can use those, too

Comment: I have forked your fiddle and entered the text that I plan on splitting into pages: http://jsfiddle.net/Uxuub/. I believe this is more complicated than a simple regex, also because I don't want the markup to break or tear (like <ul></ul> on the same page). I had hoped for an advanced jquery plugin